# Can inductance or resistance be negative or "infinite"?

Tags: electric-circuits, inductance

[image]

Since the potential different or voltage drop is positive (am I allow to say **voltage drop** or **potential difference** in the presence of a changing current?), the current flows from right to left since $\Delta V$ is positive. That is, $V_b$ is at a higher **potential** than $V_a$.

Case (1), Increasing current.

So traversing from b to a (in the direction of the current) I get a

$-IR - LI' = 9 \implies -2R - 0.5L = 9$

I get $-IR$ because the voltage drops from a higher to a lower potential as it crosses the resistor. I get $-LI'$ because since the current is increasing, the inductor opposes this increase by "becoming" a battery with - on the "a" side and + on the "b" side and I should get a voltage drop across that.

Case (2), Decreasing current.

So traversing from b to a (in the direction of the current) I get a

$-IR + LI' = 5 \implies -2R - 0.5L = 5$

I get $-IR$ because the voltage drops from a higher to a lower potential as it crosses the resistor. I get $LI'$ because since the current is decreasing, the inductor opposes this decrease by "becoming" a battery with + on the "a" side and - on the "b" side and I should get +V by gaining potential.

Solving

http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=RowReduce{{-0.5%2C-2%2C9}%2C{-0.5%2C-2%2C5}}

I get some absurd answer. What is wrong with my argument?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$V_{AB} = V_A - V_B$ so node A is more positive than node B side when $V_{AB}>0$

According to the Passive Reference Convention, current enters the positive terminal of a resistor so the current is from node A to node B.

We have

$V_{AB} = 2A \cdot R + 0.5A/s \cdot L = 9V$

and

$V_{AB} = 2A \cdot R - 0.5A/s \cdot L = 5V$

which yields

$R = 3.5 \Omega$

$L = 4 H$

[EDIT]:  Given the numerous questions jak has asked in the comments, I've added a drawing to aid in "seeing" how to get the equations above.

Note that *regardless* of the direction one "travels" around the loop for KVL, you get the same equation:

$V_{ab} = V_R + V_L = IR + L\frac{dI}{dt} = 2A \cdot R + 0.5A/s \cdot L = 9V$

Also note that I take $V_{ab}$ to be the voltage across nodes a & b with the polarity shown *as per the double-subscript convention*.  And further, that I chose the current direction and passive component voltage polarities according to the *passive reference (or sign) convention*.

[image]

Comment: What? Doesn't $V_{AB}$ mean the potential difference from $V_a$ to $V_b$?

Comment: $V_{AB} > 0$ when node A is more positive than node B.  Colloquially, $V_{AB}$ is the voltage read by a voltmeter when the read lead is place on node A and the black lead is placed on node B.

Comment: @jak, see [this](http://www.allaboutcircuits.com/vol_1/chpt_6/2.html)

Comment: Because it isn't the other way around; the way I have it is the notational *convention*:  $V_{AB}$ is the voltage *drop* from node A to node B.

Comment: Yes, so node b is final value and node a is initial final, which gives $V_b - V_a$. The way you have it in your answer is from b to a

Comment: @jak, the voltage *drop* from node A to node B is *positive* if node A is more positive than node B.  So, if $V_{AB}>0$, node A is more positive than node B.  Don't you see this?

Comment: you are using $V_a - V_b$ definition. Here is a picture of what I mean http://s10.postimage.org/4lkv1qps9/K_E.jpg

Comment: @jak, in the diagram you linked to, $\Delta V$ is the voltage *rise*.  By simply looking at that diagram, you can verify all that I've written.  The current enters the $a$ terminal which is "higher V" than the $b$ terminal, correct?  So, the voltage *drops* from $a$ to $b$.  The voltage *drop* across the resistor, $V_{ab}$ is, *by Ohm's Law*, $IR$, *not* $-IR$.  And, in that diagram, $V_a - V_b = IR$.  Any further questions?

Comment: What do you mean voltage *rise*, it comes from a high potential and it *drops down* to a lower a potential, it's climbing down hill, you lose potential

Comment: http://s12.postimage.org/qlenhmrgt/rre.jpg I think this is what you mean? Maybe I wasn't explicit, but I went against the current.

Comment: @jak, please see slides 2 and 3 here: www.digilentinc.com/classroom/realanalog/text/Lecture2.ppt

Comment: In your work, you have 2R + 0.5L where you have 2R first, are you traversing from b to a? With the assumption the current flows from node a to node b like that slide?

Comment: @jak, I'm not traversing or travelling.  I'm adding to voltage drops together:  $V_{ab} = V_L + V_R = V_R + V_L$.  It's a sum, the order doesn't matter.

Comment: @jak, see the added diagram and info to my answer.  Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Your formulas are false. In both case you have : RI+LI'=U.
That gives you : 2R+0.5L=9 and 2R-0.5L=5
So R=3.5 Ohm; L=4 Henry

Notice: The arrow in potential indicates the highest potential Va. Current flows from the highest potential to the lowest as would do a stream down a mountain.

Comment: Why do you have $+IR$? $\Delta V_{ab} = V_b - V_a > 0 \iff V_b > V_a$

Comment: With method, it is quite simple:
1) Find which of Va or Vb is the greatest
2) Current flows from the greatest potential to the lowest.
3) Write the potential for each component. In a resistror and in an inductance, the current flows from the highest potential to the lowest: U=R*I; U=L*di/dt